# Static method variable issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, static-methods

I created class for handling sounds. But I've problem to stop sound? I can't send variable from playSound to stopSound AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID).
How to handle this? I really don't want instantiate it or I've to?

```
@implementation SoundPlayer
+(void)playSound:(NSString *)filename ofType:(NSString *)extension {
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:extension];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); // error - soundID is undeclared
}

+(void)stopSound
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either have to pass the id to stopSound (the same as when you play sound), or else if your audio player only plays 1 sound at a time, store the soundID as a static param on the class when you play.

Comment: and how can I declare static param?

Comment: `@interface TheClass : NSObject
+ (int)count;
@end` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035824/objective-c-static-class-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can create soundID as ivar, something like:

```
@interface SoundPlayer(){
     SystemSoundID soundID;
}
@end
```

Other way use it as global variable

Comment: I tried it as a first option before posting to stackverflow. Instance variable accessed in class method.